# pyinstaller Unable to access file

Tags: python, pygame, pyinstaller

I wrote a simple code in python/pygame, and the game was running fine in both sublime text and cmd, but when I tried to make it a exe file pyinstaller --onefile version2.py, I got an error and I don't know what is the problem ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Well bro, I don't know if I will be helpfull to you know after 6 days, I am having 2 solutions for you which worked for me today.

1. **Disable Antivirus OR put that folder in which you are building app.exe to Exception, like I have done below [Mandatory Process].**
   [image]

2. **Dont' run pyinstaller command from the directory where app.py application is present.**
   a) Get out from that directory/folder
   b) Create new directory/folder
   c) Enter that directory and start cmd in that directory/folder by pressing (shift + MouseRightClick )
   d) And then run the command

   ```
   pyinstaller --name "MyApp" "python script file path of which you want to create .exe file"
   ```

Where "MyApp" is the name which you want to give to the file after it is build successfully

**For Example**

```
pyinstaller --name "FileRenamer" "G:\data\python\Project\Bunch File Renamer\rename.py"
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to disable the anti-virus, that worked for me

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).